# Image layer with *locally* stored image

Tags: openlayers-3

I would like to add an image layer to a map using OpenLayers 3. The image file is stored *locally*, not on the web. The OL 2 documentation says that the image must be accessible on the web: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html, however, it seems to be possible to use a local basemap: [Using openlayers with a local basemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589308/using-openlayers-with-a-local-basemap). There is no HTTP server running on the local system.

The starting point is the static image example on the OL website: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/static-image.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Static Image</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script>
    // Map views always need a projection.  Here we just want to map image
    // coordinates directly to map coordinates, so we create a projection that uses
    // the image extent in pixels.
    var extent = [0, 0, 1024, 968];
    var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
      code: 'xkcd-image',
      units: 'pixels',
      extent: extent
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Image({
          source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
            attributions: [
              new ol.Attribution({
                html: '&copy; <a href="http://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>'
              })
            ],
            url: 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png',
            projection: projection,
            imageExtent: extent
          })
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
        zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 8
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png should be replaced by the path to a local file. file://... does not work for me. The OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was confused. I use OpenLayers online, and I think the map is rendered at the server. So, I guess I cannot use local files, can I?

Comment: The map is rendered at the client side and you can use local files being served by a web server.